# Find value of a in following number theory question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I find all real numbers a such that 4 < a < 5 and  a(a-3{a}) is an integer. here {a} is an fractional part of a.

Comment: What are your works so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $a=4+x$, where $x \in (0,1)$, we need $f(x) = (4+x)(4+x-3x) = (4+x)(4-2x)$ to be an integer. Rewriting we obtain
\begin{align}
f(x) & = 2(4+x)(2-x) \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
Further on the interval $(0,1)$, we have $f(x)$ to be decreasing from $16$ to $10$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, the integer values that $f(x)$ takes are $11,12,13,14$ and $15$. Each of this gives a value of $x$ from which you can find the value of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to above.

Since $\{a\}=a-\lfloor{a}\rfloor$ and $4<a<5$, therefore $\{a\}=a-4$. Substituting this to $a(a-3\{a\})\in\mathbb{Z}$ (given), you will see that $$-2a^2+12a\in\mathbb{Z}$$ If $a=4$, the value of above expression will be 16, and if $a=5$, you will get 10. So $a(a-3\{a\})$ must be integers between 10 to 16, but not equal to 10 and 16. Just equate $-2a(a-6)$ to those integers to solve for $a$. Remove $a$ that does not satisfy $4<a<5$ (in case those exist).